# Is it possible to setup a dynamic child directive?

Tags: angularjs

Would it be possible to setup a dynamic child directive within a parent directive?

In the example below, where I've used an element directive, I'm seeing '' in my view where the child should be.

If I use an attribute directive, I get '<>' instead.

I'm guessing there's maybe a better way to go about this? I essentially just wanted to be able to use whatever child directive I wanted in the parent 'tile' directive.

**Definitions**

```
  // Tile
  .directive('tile', function () {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        child: '@',
        heading: '@',
        icon: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'templates/tile.tpl.html',
      transclude: true
    };
  })

  // Stats Table
  .directive('statsTable', function () {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<h1>Table</h1>',
    };
  });
```

**Markup**

```
<tile child="stats-table" heading="Users" icon="user"></tile>
```

**Templates**

```
<article class="tile">

  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{icon}}"></i>
  <h2>{{heading}}</h2>    

  <{{child}}></{{child}}>

</article>
```

**EDIT** - One thing to add: I need to also pass data through to the child as well. Something like this:

```
<parent child-data="childData"></parent>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/susoq8a1/. I dont think there is binding for tag so you must append child tag name inside your parent directive and assign the scope of parent to the child tag using $compile.

Comment: Also the binding of childData from parent scope to child scope can be done easily because both are now sharing the same scope.